# The following classes could not be found - android.support.design.widget.tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle

I want to add tab-layout to my page interface, When I drag the tab-layout from the tools it is showing me following error

following classes could not be found - `android.support.design.widget.tablayout
android.support.design.widget.TabItem`.

My dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

what i can do to solve this error ?!

and this is my xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.amr.tsepas_project.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did u imported class in java file

Comment: what class?????

Comment: I have just added below line to dependency, and its working

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

Comment: post you build.gradle file.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'